# Start a WPF MVVM application as either GUI or command line? (As a service)

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-services, caliburn.micro

What changes I need to make if I am using Caliburn Micro as the MVVM framework to make my application to run either as GUI or as a command line app (so it can be used as a Windows Service).

Comment: Command line applications are *not* the same thing as Windows Services. They're meant to run in the console subsystem, the thing you get by opening up the Windows Command Prompt. A Windows Service is something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Don't declare a `StartupUri` but instead register to the `StartUp` event in your `Application`.

In the event you could read an argument to distinguish between opening a `Window` or not.

So for example:

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             Startup="App_OnStartup">
</Application>
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Args.Contains("Console"))
        {
            //do stuff
        }
        else
        {
            new MainWindow().Show();
        }
    }
}
```